# Как определить в какую сторону поворачивать роботу?

Tags: python, математика, геометрия

У меня есть программа управления роботом. Робот получает координаты цели и , зная свои координаты (x, y, theta), должен повернуться к цели. Для поворота ему надо послать команду self.geometry_msg.angular.z с отрицательным значением (для поворота по часовой) или положительным (против часовой). Вопрос в том как понять в какую сторону ему поворачивать? Сейчас он не всегда верно выбирает кратчайший угл поворота. Как это исправить? Формулу с math.atan2 нашёл в интернете.

```
                angle = math.atan2(y_goal - self.y, x_goal - self.x) - self.theta

                if abs(angle) > 0.1:

                    self.geometry_msg.angular.z = 0.5*angle/abs(angle)
                    self.geometry_msg.linear.x = 0.3

                else: 

                    self.geometry_msg.angular.z = 0 
                    self.geometry_msg.linear.x = 1              

                self.velocity_publisher.publish(self.geometry_msg)
```

x_goal - x координата цели

y_goal - y координата цели

self.x - x координата робота

self.y - y координата робота

self.theta - угл поворота робота относительно  OX

Угл theta считается от 0 до 6,28 (против часовой) и до -6,28 (по часовой)

abs(angle) > 0.1 это условие можно менять, просто мне не нужна высокая точность поворота, достаточно точности 0.1 (в радинах).

Comment: 1. Если у вас поворот на 270 градусов вы будете куда вращатся? Вот именно, вам нужно заложить условие, что если угол поворота больше 180 (3.14 рад), или меньше -180 (-3.14 рад) то делать 360 минус "ваш градус".

Comment: 2. С артангенс плохо работает на малых(если не ошибаюсь) градусах. Нужно добавить условие, что на том промежутке, где артангенс "плохо" считает, брать 90+аркотангенс и развернуть x и у, т.е. для половины углов подходит `math.atan2(y_goal - self.y, x_goal - self.x)` а для второй `arcctg2( x_goal - self.x, y_goal - self.y)`. это вам добавит точности. Возможно этот факт в библиотеке учли... а возможно нет.

Comment: а ещё можно `self.theta` превратить в направляющий вектор, тогда знак координаты оси Z векторного произведения этого вектора на желаемый даст направление поворота.